# Error de funcion

Tags: python

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver.El programa funciona una parte bien pero al agregar una función mas find_movie(),esta tiene como funcionalidad mostrar y agregar las películas agregadas mas las que busca. funciones ingresan lo que el usuario tipea luego las imprime
pero por alguna razon no me las trae y da un error.

```
movies=[]
def menu():
    user=input("Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x ")
    while user  != "x":
        if  user  == "a":
            add_movie()
        elif user == "l":
            show_movie(movies)
        elif user == "f":
            find_movie()
        else:
            print("intente otra vez")
        user = input("Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x ")
#ingresamos mediante imputs
def add_movie():
    name=input("Enter de movie name :")
    autor=input("Enter de movie director :")
    year=int(input("Enter de movie director :"))

    movies.append({
        "name":name,
        "autor":autor,
        "year":year
    })
#para mostrar tenemos que recorrer
 #el diccionario mediante for
def show_movie(movie_list):
     for movie in movie_list:
         show_details_movie(movie)

def show_details_movie(movie):
        print(f"""this is name: {movie["name"]}""")
        print(f"""this is name: {movie["autor"]}""")
        print(f"""this is name: {movie["year"]}""")
def find_movie():
    find_by = input("What property of the movie are you looking for? ")
    looking_for = input("What are you searching for? ")
    found_movies = find_by_attribute(movies, looking_for, lambda x : x[find_by])
    show_movie(found_movies)

def find_by_attribute(items, expected, finder):
    found=[]

    for i in items:
        if finder (i) == expected:
            found.append(i)
    return found

menu()
```

---

RESULTADO:

```
Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x a
Enter de movie name :Aliens
Enter de movie director :Scott
Enter de movie director :1989
Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x l
this is name: Aliens
this is name: Scott
this is name: 1989
Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x f
What property of de movie are you looking for? aliens
What are you searshing for? Scott
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/reset/PycharmProjects/movies.py", line 59, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:/Users/reset/PycharmProjects/movies.py", line 12, in menu
    find_movie()
  File "C:/Users/reset/PycharmProjects/movies.py", line 44, in find_movie
    found_movies = find_by_attribute(movies, looking_for, lambda x: x[find_by])
  File "C:/Users/reset/PycharmProjects/movies.py", line 53, in find_by_attribute
    if finder(i) == expected:
  File "C:/Users/reset/PycharmProjects/movies.py", line 44, in <lambda>
    found_movies = find_by_attribute(movies, looking_for, lambda x: x[find_by])
KeyError: 'aliens'
```

Comment: Qué error da? Haciendo qué y con qué datos de prueba da el error?

Comment: ¿No estarás simplemente ingresando mal el primer input??En teoría `find_by` debería se `name`, `autor` o `year` no `aliens`.... El error viene por `lambda x : x[find_by]`, dónde `x` es es un item de `movies`, diccionarios que no tienen la clave `aliens`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad no entiendo muy bien tu codigo, osea la logica si, pero me enseñaron con otro tipo de sintaxis a codear python en la U :p de todas formas te digo el problema y escribire una solucion pero como a mi me enseñaron a codear sry:( bueno, primero que todo el problema reside en que estas intentando buscar una llave en el diccionario que creaste de nombre 'Aliens' la cual no existe, ahora el code:

```
movies=[]
def menu():
user=input("Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x ")
while user  != "x":
    if  user  == "a":
        add_movie()
    elif user == "l":
        show_movie(movies)
    elif user == "f":
        find_movie()
    else:
        print("intente otra vez")
    user = input("Escriba: ingresar= a,mostrar=l, encontrar=f salir=x ")
def add_movie():
name=input("Enter de movie name :")
autor=input("Enter de movie director :")
year=int(input("Enter de movie director :"))

movies.append({
    "name":name,
    "autor":autor,
    "year":year
})

def show_details_movie(movie):
    print(f"""this is name: {movie["name"]}""")
    print(f"""this is name: {movie["autor"]}""")
    print(f"""this is name: {movie["year"]}""")

def show_movie(movie_list):
for k in range(0,len(movie_list)):
    show_details_movie(movie_list[k])

def find_movie():
find_by = input("What property of the movie are you looking for? ")
looking_for = input("What are you searching for? ")
found=find_by_attribute(movies, looking_for, find_by)
show_movie(found)

def find_by_attribute(items, expected, finder):
found=[]
for k in range(0,len(items)):
    dicc=items[k]
    if dicc[str(finder)]==expected:
        found.append(dicc)
return found        

menu()
```